# Filter List items on merge of two lists RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am merging two lists of Item object and need that there's no duplicate items in the list, but I don't know how two filter the duplicate items. Here's a code snippet:

```
class Item {
    int id;
    String name;
}

//How to filter duplicate items of the list with rx???
private Observable<List<Item>> getItems() {
    return Observable.merge(getListFromSourceOne(), getListFromSourceTwo());
}

private Observable<List<Item>> getListFromSourceOne() {
    Item item1 = new Item(1, "arnold");
    Item item2 = new Item(2, "jerry");

    List<Item> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(item1);
    list.add(item2);

    return Observable.just(list);
}

private Observable<List<Item>> getListFromSourceTwo() {
    Item item1 = new Item(1, "arnold");
    Item item2 = new Item(3, "angelica");

    List<Item> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(item1);
    list.add(item2);

    return Observable.just(list);
}
```

Comment: Use distinct operator. You can find it here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables#distinct

Comment: If you're actually just working with Lists synchronously, then why are you using Rx for it?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am not. This code sample was just to ilustrate the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of options here. I'm just listing some that came to mind. Let's assume your item model implements correctly the equals method.

1. Using [distinct](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html)

Simply map the observable to something that emits the items one by one.

```
Observable.merge(getListFromSourceOne(),
               getListFromSourceTwo())
  .distinct()
  .flatMap(list -> Observable.fromIterable(list))
  .toList();
```

2. Using [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html)

Basically convert the list into a set, which removes duplicates and then back to a list. Quite a lot of unnecessary operations to be honest.

```
Observable.merge(getListFromSourceOne(),
                  getListFromSourceTwo())
  .map(list -> new HashSet(list))
  .map(set -> new ArrayList(set));
```

3. Using [zip](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#zip)

Don't even use merge:

```
 getListFromSourceOne()
  .zipWith(getListFromSourceTwo(), (list1, list2) -> {
      List<Item> result = new ArrayList(list1);

      for(Item I : list2)
         if(!result.contains(I))
            result.add(I);
    });
```

Again not the most efficient thing in the world.

4. Something else

I guess the best option is using `distinct` and maybe plug it even before you're turning lists:

```
private Observable<List<Item>> getItems() {
  return Observable.merge(getListFromSourceOne(), getListFromSourceTwo())
                .distinct()
                .toList();
}

private Observable<Item> getListFromSourceOne() {
  Item item1 = new Item(1, "arnold");
  Item item2 = new Item(2, "jerry");

  return Observable.just(item2, item2);
}

private Observable<List<Item>> getListFromSourceTwo() {
  Item item1 = new Item(1, "arnold");
  Item item2 = new Item(3, "angelica");

  return Observable.just(item2, item2);
}
```